# Wind not working (ver 2.83)

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

Simple quick setup following tutorial, but wind not working. Cloth hanging properly, but wind @ 20000 force has no effect.

What am I missing?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YK3ljOQW6vr7ZMqKjwcZX0Pv9OOp5Yji/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine, you just have to move your force emitter "in front of" (behind) your object. Make it so the arrow points at the cloth. See below:

[image]

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks.